# Error while using Verbatiminput

Tags: errors, verbatim, matlab

I have the following Error in my .log-File:

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
<read 1> {
           Undefined function or variable 'generateFilename'.
l.80 \verbatiminput{MasterFile.txt}
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with that? I am wondering because it was running the whole time but now it tells me this over and over again.

Appreciate your help guys!

Comment: that usually means that you have a NULL (character 0)  in the file. `\catcode0=12` would allow nulls (although they typically do not produce sensible typeset output)

Comment: That is very disturbing also regarding the fact that the script has been running before and the text file did not change at all...
Where can I put this code you mentioned?

Comment: anywhere before you input the file but usually a null in the file indicates some kind of data corruption, so simply allowing them may not be best, it would however confirm that that is the ssue

Comment: Yeah makes sense. It is really frustrating since it is just a .txt file. Any other ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: not sure what you mean, either you have to change the file production to make sure it doesn't write nulls or you have to use the catcode declaration to allow nulls to be read. probably the first of those is better but off topic for this site as it's an issue with the file generation (matlab?)

Comment: I deleted the .txt file, close MATLAB and restarted the whole process. Now it works perfectly. Whatever... :) Was probably a bug by rerunning this text file generation over and over again the whole day. Thanks for your time mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually means that you have a NULL (character 0) in the file.

```
\catcode0=12
```

anywhere before the file is input would allow nulls (although they typically do not produce sensible typeset output) .